# SQL Azure and Indexed Views

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have some Premium Azure SQL Databases, and we are attempting to use indexed views to materialize a subset of some larger tables, so the data can be used in some search / reportring queries. What I am noticing is that the query optimizer refuses to use the view.

My first attempt was to create the view and not modify the query. I thought the optimizer would substitute the view when it determined it was a better choice, but it didn't.

My second attempt I selected from the view directly, the execution plan didn't change at all.

Finally I added the (NOEXPAND) hint on the view and this time the plan did use the indexed view.

I've seen this behavior with 3 different indexed views in 3 different queries. In all 3 cases the queries performed at several orders of magnitude better. In my most recent example the duration of the query went from 90 seconds to 1 second.

I'm not a big fan of using hints to override the query optimizer, has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Did you clear the queryplan cache and see if this had the desired affect?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes views are fully supported on Azure SQL Database Premium. No functionality of indexed views is blocked or not supported on Azure SQL Database.

To be able to help you, you will have to share the database schema and a step-by-step procedure of how your reproduce the issue. I guess you won't agree to share the schema on this site, so maybe the best you can do is create a support ticket at Azure Support. Please send an email to this (azcommunity@microsoft.com) address explaining the issue,  they will return instructions to have this handled by Azure Support. They will safely take a look at your schema.

Comment: thanks will go that route, can't post the schema and can't seem to easily recreate it with a simpler schema.

Comment: I know, that's why they told me you should proceed to create the ticket.